# Rock, Paper, Scissors random match not working

Tags: java

How do you make the player play for a random number of match and then end the game with all the score?

I'm trying to do a loop that let a player play a number of matches and ask at the end if still want to play or not.

```
public class RockPaperScissors {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner playername = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name;
        int playerChoose;
        int aiChoose;
        String match = "";
        int matchCount = 1;
        int matchLimit = 10;
        boolean endMatch = true;
        int Rock = 1, Paper = 2, Scissor = 3;

        //Player choose how many round.               
        int max = 10;
        int min = 1;
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + 1;

        // Computer random choose Rock, Paper or Scissor.
        int maxme = 3;
        int minme = 1;
        aiChoose = rand.nextInt((maxme - minme) + 1) + 1;

        System.out.println("Hi, what is your name?");
        name = playername.next();

        System.out.println("Hi, " + name);

        System.out.println("Let's play Rock, Paper and Scissor!!");

        System.out.println("How many round do you want to play?");

        // loop match I'm doing something wrong

        while (!match.equals(randomNum)) {
            System.out.println(randomNum + " match");
            if (randomNum == 0) 

            {
                System.out.println("Chooses between Rock - 1, Paper - 2 and Scissor - 3? ");
            }
            playerChoose = sc.nextInt();

            //Check Player choise for Rock Paper and Scissor
            if (playerChoose < 1 || playerChoose > 3) {
                System.out.println("Wrong Choise");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            System.out.println(aiChoose);

            if (playerChoose == aiChoose) {
                System.out.println("We tie");
            } else if ((playerChoose == Rock && aiChoose == Scissor) || (playerChoose == Scissor && aiChoose == Paper) || (playerChoose == Paper && aiChoose == Rock));
            {
                System.out.println("You win");
            }



    }
}
```

Comment: welcome in our community ..... plz read this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
it will be help to improve your question quality

Comment: Well I think you should increase the match number inside of the loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a specific amount of round you can do it with a for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfMatches; i++){
}
```

If you want to let the user decide if he wants to play you could do something like this:

```
while(true){
//all the things before
System.out.println("Do you still want to play? ")
if(sc.next.equals("No")){
break;
}
}
```